# Django - check if user has been redirected to current page

Tags: django, validation, redirect, get, request

I am using Django 1.5 and I want to check if the user has been redirected to my login page because he tried to access another page which required a login without being logged in. Suppose there is this view called 'securityPage' and suppose that view is called when I visit the

```
/securityInfo/
```

URL. Assuming this is the securityPage view:

```
@login_required
def securityPage(request):
    #some code
```

Now when I visit that URL, it redirects me to the login.html page, which is correct (since the user - me - is not logged into any account). This is my login.html:

```
{% if 'next' in request.GET %}
    <p>You must first login into your account before having access to the page you were trying to view.</p>
{% endif %}
```

for some reason, even though I am being redirected and the URL of the login page I am redirected to is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?next=/securityInfo/
```

, the line

```
{% if 'next' in request.GET %}
```

evaluates to false even when 'next' is in the URL. Any idea why?

Comment: Next is not in the current request (the redirect), it will be on the next request (hence the name "next" for the variable), when the user logs in, because "next" will be sent when the login form is sent.

Comment: @Jingo hm, but I thought it just checks to see if the string 'next' is in the URL.. how do I make it so that it checks whether the user has been redirected to the current page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think request object is part of the default context values.

check your template_context_processors in your settings and if you add **django.core.context_processors.request** in that list then the current request will be added to every requestcontext. or just pass the request manually for that view.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request